# Best Way To Make High Quality Reports With Asp.Net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, report

In our project We made reports with the method that return as a datatable from a class with dynamic sql.

Nowadays, we think to migrate to more professional technic for our reports. For this purpose I examine crystal report and devexpress' XtraReport components.

However, I Couldn't decide which component and method(dynamic sql, stored procedure etc.) should I use.

Can anyone help me about this?

Answer (score 1):

We have been using Crystal Reports but it is just a pain to work with, had a lot of issues on DataSets and the way we passed data to the reports etc. We are now using DevExpress's XtraReport, not as powerful as Crystal but you do have a lot more control over the report than in Crystal